# How do I use a Parameter form to select whether or not I want null values?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a database that my school uses for student recruitment. I want to include an option on the parameter form used to generate a students contact information that allows the user to select whether or not to include "applied" students in that contact list. I am currently trying to do that by using a select query that pulls data based on whether or not the "IdNumber" field is null. When I run the attached SQL, it doesn't pull any data at all. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT InterestCards.NotStudentID, InterestCards.Email, InterestCards.YearOfGraduation, 
InterestCards.SourceTwoLocation, InterestCards.FirstName, InterestCards.LastName, 
InterestCards.Program, InterestCards.Inactive, InterestCards.IDNumber 
FROM InterestCards 
WHERE (((InterestCards.Email)<>"no email") 
AND ((InterestCards.YearOfGraduation) Like [Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![GradYear] & "*") 
AND ((InterestCards.SourceTwoLocation) Like [Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![FairName] & "*") 
AND ((InterestCards.Inactive)=No) 
AND ((InterestCards.IDNumber)=Switch([Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![IncludeApplied]=0,Null,[forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![IncludeApplied]=(-1),([InterestCards].[IDNumber]) Is Not Null Or ([InterestCards].[IDNumber]) Is Null)) 
AND ((InterestCards.HighSchool) Like [Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![HighSchool] & "*") 
AND ((InterestCards.SourceThreeType) Like [Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![SelectTerm] & "*") 
AND ((InterestCards.DateEntered) Between Nz([Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![StartDate],#1/1/1900#) And Nz([Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![EndDate],#1/1/2199#)));
```

Comment: You cannot check for null using equality operators, thus your Switch statement is not effective.  Within SQL you can use `Is Null` operator, or you can also use the VBA function `IsNull()`.  You'll need to change your Switch function into another equivalent boolean expression.

Comment: The other problem with the Switch statement is that the `<value-2>` parameter is a boolean value that will always return True.  In that case, you would be comparing IDNumber (I assume an interger value?) with a boolean True value.  Altogether the Switch statement just does not make sense.  See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379

Answer (score 0):

Operators cannot be dynamic in a query object. Cannot be selected via a conditional expression. However, parameters can be dynamic. Suggest you construct a field with an expression that handles the nulls to return either of 2 values:

`IIf([IDNumber] Is Null, "XXXX", "AAAA") AS Grp`

Then to select either the Null or not Null records, apply conditional parameter to that field:

`Grp = IIf([Forms]![MassCommunicationTool]![IncludeApplied]=0, "XXXX", "AAAA")`

I've never used dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to construct filter criteria and apply to form or report.